# ReactiveCocoa : Chain a signal with a repeating signal

Tags: ios, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, racsignal

Using ReactiveCocoa, how can I chain a signal from a repeating one?

I would like to do something like this:
Every 5 seconds, I run a network request.

For this purpose, I created a repeating signal

```
RACSignal *each5SecondSignal = [[[RACSignal interval:5 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] take:1] concat:[RACSignal 5 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]];
```

and a signal for fetching data

```
RACSignal* iframeSignal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {....
```

But I don't know how to chain those. Here are my attempt (with the 'then' method).

```
//This doesn't work, the log do not appear
[[each5SecondSignal then:^RACSignal *{
   return iframeSignal;
 }] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
   NSLog(@"Request was made");
 }];
```

However, when I do `[iframeSignal subscribeNext...]` the content of the signal is called, and when I do

```
//OK is logged every 5 seconds
[each5SecondSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"OK");
  }];
```

the log appears as expected.

Could you help me?

Sincerely

Jery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `each5SecondSignal` can be much simpler. You don't have to call `take:` as it will cause the signal to complete after 5 seconds, and if I understood you correctly you want the signal to go on forever.

```
RACSignal *each5SecondSignal = [RACSignal interval:5 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
```

And you can use `flattenMap:` so that `iframeSignal` is called each time `each5SecondSignal` sends next value (which happens every 5 seconds):

```
[[each5SecondSignal flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
   return iframeSignal;
 }] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
   NSLog(@"Request was made");
 }];
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem, and your answer works. I don't understand why it doesn't work with 'then'. In the github example of chaining operations, it uses both 'flattenMap' and 'then'. Thank you if you can enlighten me ;)

Comment: `then` executes the second signal after the first one completes, `flattenMap`- after the first signal sends next. The'timer' signal never completes, it only sends next values.